# JPA attributes of a Derived entity are not loaded when it contains SAX code

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, glassfish, sax

I'm using a single table inheritance as explained [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Example_single_table_inheritance_table) in a Glassfish 3.1 environment. So far, everything works as expected. But after adding some code into the derived entity to parse an xml String, JPA does not load the attributes of the base entity anymore.

I've set up an example netbeans project to reproduce this problem, you can download it from [github here](https://github.com/stestaub/entityLoadingBug).

Here is the base entity defining the discriminator field and a testField:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator")
@XmlRootElement
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String testField;
    private String discriminator;

    public String getDiscriminator() {
        return discriminator;
    }

    public void setDiscriminator(String discriminator) {
        this.discriminator = discriminator;
    }

    public String getTestField() {
        return testField;
    }

    public void setTestField(String testField) {
        this.testField = testField;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof BaseEntity)) {
            return false;
        }
        BaseEntity other = (BaseEntity) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.ce.entityloadingbug.entites.NewEntity[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

And here is the code of the derived entity, with a private methode containing the code that causes jpa to not load the fields anymore...

```
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

/**
 *
 * @author stefan
 */
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("derived")
public class DerivedEntity extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * The problem code
     */
    private void theProblemCode() {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db;
        try {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            // This is the line that makes Problems!!
            Document doc = db.parse("");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as I remove the line "Document doc = db.parse("")" everything works again. As you can see the problem exists although the code that causes the problem is never called.

My current solouting is to move that code into a innerclass. But I don't like it because I do not know what the Problem is.

Please feel free to download my example project from github and try it.

Here is my Setup that I used to reproduce that bug:

- Glassfish 3.1.1
- NetBeans IDE 7.0.1
- Database: Derby 10.6.2.1
- JPA: EclipseLink 2.3

In fact, all libraries I used were shiped with the NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 setup for Linux.
.
Thank you for any answers or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is very odd.  Check you log for errors, or any logging.  Enable logging on finest in EclipseLink in your persistence.xml, so odd is occurring.

Ensure both classes are listed in your persistence.xml.

Also try disabling weaving ("eclipselink.weaving"="false"), does that affect the issue?

Also include the SQL that is logged, does it select the data?

Comment: Hi James, thx very much, disabling weaving does the trick. I don't know why but it seems it optimizes a bit too much :). The logs seems fine, no errors and the select does it's work. I think i will post a bugreport on eclipselink, but for now disabling weaving should be ok.

Comment: Edit: Setting weaving to static also works... so i can still use Lazy loading.